# Replacing a number in a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a function that finds the first smallest value and returns it from a 2d array:

```java
public static int getMinimumValueOfTerrain(int[][] terrain) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int row = 0; row < terrain.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < terrain[row].length; col++) {
            min = Math.min(min, terrain[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

I have another function that supposed to replace the found smallest value with its minus value:

```java
public static int[][] replaceMinusValue(int[][] terrain) {
    for (int row = 0; row < terrain.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < terrain[row].length; col++) {
            int tempValue = getMinimumValueOfTerrain(terrain);
            int minusValue = -tempValue;
        }
    }
    return terrain;
}
```

Example:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |

Expected outcome:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | -1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |

How can I approach it with my functions?

Comment: Do you want to replace the element in place or you want to have new array returned from second function?

Comment: I would like to return it from second function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster implementation would be to detect the row and column coordinates of the minimum value and modify this value:

```java
public static int[][] findAndReplaceMinValue(int[][] terrain) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minRow = -1, minCol = -1;

    for (int row = 0; row < terrain.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < terrain[row].length; col++) {
            if (terrain[row][col] < min) {
                min = terrain[row][col];
                minRow = row;
                minCole = col;
            }     
        }
    }
    if (minRow != -1 && minCol != -1) {
        terrain[minRow][minCol] *= -1;
    }
    return terrain;
}
```

If existing method `getMinimumValueOfTerrain` has to be reused in `getMinimumValueOfTerrain`, the `min` element should be re-found once again and `break` out of the nested loop may be applied:

```java
public static int[][] replaceMinusValue(int[][] terrain) {
    int min = getMinimumValueOfTerrain(terrain);

    out: 
    for (int row = 0; row < terrain.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < terrain[row].length; col++) {
            if (min == terrain[row][col]) {
                terrain[row][col] *= -1; // or -min
                break out;
            }    
        }
    }
    return terrain;
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex! This is what I was trying to approach. Because I wanted to return a new array using the second function. Now I understand the logic too.

Answer (score 2):

You should also keep `min`’s row and column indices in `getMinimumValueOfTerrain`. After `for` loops, you can change `terrain[minRow][minColumn]` with its negative. I think only `getMinimumValueOfTerrain` method is enough if there is no constraint. If there is, you can write another function that returns 2-element array of indices.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options. If you are only doing this once or efficiency does not matter, you can loop through the entire array and find the smallest element, then replace the element. For example:

```
public static void replaceMinusValue(int[][] terrain) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minI = -1;
    int minJ = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < terrain.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < terrain[i].length; j++) {
            if (terrain[i][j] < min) {
                min = terrain[i][j];
                minI = i;
                minJ = j;
            }
        }
    }

    terrain[minI][minJ] *= -1;
}
```

Would do that. Notice that you don't need to return the terrain after you do the flip (Just like you don't return a new array when sorting).

Comment: If non-strict condition `<= min` is used, then the _last_ minimum value will be replaced.

Comment: Hi! I haven't checked but I guess this solution replacing all the min numbers with its minus value right?

Comment: @HuserB1989 this one only replaces one if multiple instances of the same value exist. However, a slight modification allows the replacement of all of them.